# TypeError: register is not a function in react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have three components for form:

1. CreateInvoice.js (Parent component Form)
2. Item.js (Child Component)
3. Input.js (simple input with some styling)
   When I try to access the `register` method to the Item.js file using this code `const { register } = useFormContext();`, it shows me this error message

```
TypeError: register is not a function
Input
src/components/Input.js:5
  2 | 
  3 | const Input = ({ inputName, readOnly, register }) => {
  4 |     return (
> 5 |         <input {...(readOnly && { disabled: true, readOnly, value: 0 })} type="text" id={inputName} className="w-full bg-primaryOne p-3 rounded-md shadow-md border border-borderOne focus:outline-none focus:border-secondaryOne transition text-white font-bold text-xs" {...register(inputName, { required: true })} />
  6 |     )
  7 | }
  8 |
```

But When I directly call useForm in Item.js, it doesn't show me an error message and when I add a new item to the form, it appends an empty object to the invoices array like this.
[image]

Anyone, please help me to fix this.

Input component code(Input.js):

```
import React from 'react'

const Input = ({ inputName, readOnly, register }) => {
    return (
        <input {...(readOnly && { disabled: true, readOnly, value: 0 })} type="text" id={inputName} className="w-full bg-primaryOne p-3 rounded-md shadow-md border border-borderOne focus:outline-none focus:border-secondaryOne transition text-white font-bold text-xs" {...register(inputName, { required: true })} />
    )
}

export default Input
```

Whole form code(CreateInvoice.js):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useForm, Controller, useFieldArray, FormProvider } from "react-hook-form";
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker'
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import Label from './Label';
import Input from './Input';
import Item from './Item';
// import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
// import { createInvoice } from '../actions/invoices';

const CreateInvoice = ({ openForm, setOpenForm }) => {
    const { register, control, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();
    const [newItems, setNewItems] = useState([]);

    const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray({
        control,
        name: "invoices"
    });
    // const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const onSubmit = data => {
        console.log(data);
        // dispatch(createInvoice(data));
    };
    return (
        <div className={`transition ${!openForm ? 'transform translate-x-full hidden' : '-translate-x-full'}`}>
            <div className="fixed top-0 left-0 flex items-center justify-center w-full h-screen z-10" onClick={() => setOpenForm(!openForm)}></div>
            <div className="fixed top-0 left-0 z-20 ml-24">
                <FormProvider >
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="w-screen max-w-2xl h-screen bg-primaryTwo p-14">
                        <h1 className="text-white text-2xl font-bold mb-10">Create Invoice</h1>
                        <div className="overflow-scroll w-full h-full flex flex-col pr-7 content-area pb-10">
                            <small className="text-secondaryTwo font-bold text-xs">Bill Form</small>
                            <div>
                                <Label labelName="Street Address" />
                                <Input inputName="streetAddress" register={register} />
                            </div>
                            <div className="flex justify-between flex-wrap">
                                <div>
                                    <Label labelName="City" />
                                    <Input inputName="city" register={register} />
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <Label labelName="Post Code" />
                                    <Input inputName="postCode" register={register} />
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <Label labelName="Country" />
                                    <Input inputName="country" register={register} />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <small className="text-secondaryTwo font-bold text-xs mt-8">Bill To</small>
                            <div>
                                <Label labelName="Client Name" />
                                <Input inputName="clientName" register={register} />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <Label labelName="Client Email" />
                                <Input inputName="clientEmail" register={register} />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <Label labelName="Street Address" />
                                <Input inputName="clientStreetAddress" register={register} />
                            </div>
                            <div className="flex flex-wrap justify-between">
                                <div>
                                    <Label labelName="City" />
                                    <Input inputName="clientCity" register={register} />
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <Label labelName="Post Code" />
                                    <Input inputName="clientPostCode" register={register} />
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <Label labelName="Country" />
                                    <Input inputName="clientCountry" register={register} />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="flex justify-between">
                                <div className="w-1/2 mr-2">
                                    <Label labelName="Invoice Date" />
                                    <Controller
                                        control={control}
                                        name="paymentDue"
                                        render={({ field }) => (
                                            <DatePicker
                                                className="w-full bg-primaryOne p-3 rounded-md shadow-md border border-borderOne focus:outline-none focus:border-secondaryOne transition text-white font-bold text-xs"
                                                onChange={(date) => field.onChange(date)}
                                                selected={field.value}
                                            />
                                        )}
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div className="w-1/2 ml-2">
                                    <Label labelName="Payment Terms" />
                                    <select className="w-full bg-primaryOne p-3 rounded-md shadow-md border border-borderOne focus:outline-none focus:border-secondaryOne transition text-white font-bold text-xs" name="Payments Term" id="Payments Term" {...register("Payments Term", { required: true })}>
                                        <option value="1">Next 1 Day</option>
                                        <option value="7">Next 7 Days</option>
                                        <option value="14">Next 14 Days</option>
                                        <option value="30">Next 30 Days</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <Label labelName="Descriptions" />
                                <Input inputName="descriptions" register={register} />
                            </div>
                            <p className="text-gray-500 text-lg mt-6 mb-2 font-bold">Item List</p>
                            <div>
                                // in this code I need help
                                {fields.map((invoice, index) => <Item key={invoice.id} index={index} remove={remove} />)}
                            </div>
                            <button className="w-full bg-borderOne hover:bg-primaryOne transition text-white border-none rounded-full mt-4 p-4 text-xs font-bold flex justify-center" onClick=
                                {e => {
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                    append({});
                                }}
                            >
                                <span className="font-semibold mr-1">+</span>Add New Item
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div className="flex justify-between py-4">jsx

                            <button className="rounded-full text-neutral text-xs bg-primaryOne outline-none px-8 py-4 font-bold" onClick={() => setOpenForm(!openForm)}>Discard</button>
                            <div className="pr-7">
                                <button className="rounded-full text-neutral text-xs bg-primaryOne outline-none px-8 py-4 font-bold">Save as Draft</button>
                                <input className="rounded-full text-neutral text-xs bg-secondaryTwo outline-none ml-2 px-8 py-4 font-bold" type="submit" value="Save & Send" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </FormProvider>
            </div >

        </div >
    )
}

export default CreateInvoice
```

whole child component(Item.js) code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Input from './Input'
import Label from './Label'
import { useFormContext } from "react-hook-form";

const Item = ({ index, remove }) => {
    const { register } = useFormContext();

    return (
        <div className="flex justify-center items-end">
            <div className="w-3/5">
                <Label labelName="Item Name" />
                <Input inputName="inputName" register={register} />
            </div>
            <div className="w-2/12 mx-3">
                <Label labelName="Qty." />
                <Input inputName="quantity" register={register} />
            </div>
            <div className="w-1/3">
                <Label labelName="Price" />
                <Input inputName="price" register={register} />
            </div>
            <div className="mx-3">
                <Label labelName="Total" />
                <Input inputName="total" register={register} readOnly />
            </div>
            <button className="mb-4" aria-label="delete button" onClick={
                e => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    remove(index);
                }}
            >
                <svg className="transition fill-current text-gray-400 hover:fill-current hover:text-red-400" width="13" height="16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M11.583 3.556v10.666c0 .982-.795 1.778-1.777 1.778H2.694a1.777 1.777 0 01-1.777-1.778V3.556h10.666zM8.473 0l.888.889h3.111v1.778H.028V.889h3.11L4.029 0h4.444z" fillRule="nonzero" /></svg></button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Item
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing to spread the `formMethods` to the `<FormProvider />` in your `<CreateInvoice />` component.

```
const CreateInvoice = ({ openForm, setOpenForm }) => {
    const formMethods = useForm();
    const { register, control, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = formMethods;
    
    return (
      <FormProvider {...formMethods} >
      ...
      </FormProvider>
    );
}
```

**For the second issue:**

- you're not registering the field array item `<input />` components correctly and miss to set the `index`, so RHF can't setup the link to this `fields`. Check the demo, i just passed the `fieldId` as a prop to your `<Item />` component.
- since v7 RHF's `errors` object is a property of the `formState` property returned by `useForm`. I updated the code example above.
- you should set the `defaultValues` for your field array item when you're calling `append`. From the [docs](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usefieldarray):

> When you `append`, `prepend`, `insert` and `update` the field array, the obj can't be empty object rather need to supply all your input's `defaultValues`.

[image: Edit React Hook Form - Basic (forked)]

Comment: thanks for your help.
Now I am not getting an error message but I am not able to submit my form.

Comment: Did you fill out every field when you tested it? Because you set every `<Input />` component to be required. `onSubmit` will only get triggered when there are no errors in your form. You can check it by logging the `errors` object in your `<Createinvoice />` component and see if it is empty or not.

Comment: When I don't add a new item to the form then it submits the form but when I add a new item to the form it doesn't submit the form.
Website link: https://invoice-web-app.vercel.app/

Comment: click on New Invoice button to open a form

Comment: I am getting undefined when you do console.log(errors)

Comment: After removing required from the inputs, form is submitting but the value of the invoices array is an array of empty objects
And when I create new item in a list it automatically takes the value of the previous inputs

Comment: I updated my answer and also provided a CodeSandbox - check it out.

Comment: It works!
Thank you for going above and beyond!

Comment: One last thing why save as draft and submit button are submitting the form onclick. Only Save & Send button should submit the form

Comment: By default a `<button />` has `type="submit"`, so inside a `<form />` it would trigger the `onSubmit` event. You can either set the type like this: `<button type="button" />` or use `event.preventDefault()`inside the callback of your `onClick` handler to prevent submitting the form.

Comment: Now! It's working as expected
Thank you very much

Comment: In my item list, I have quantity and price and I want to calculate the total by multiplying quantity and price.
How should I get the value of quantity and price when the user enters it(onchange) and update the value of the total?
Just give an idea how to do that?
I'll try to do it by myself

Comment: I think I need to use useWatch but I am not able to figure out how to do that

Comment: You could do something like that with `useWatch` -> [CodeSandox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-basic-forked-5fmlx?file=/src/Item.js). This should give you an idea, but you need to check that the user can only enter valid numbers, otherwise `total` would print out `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to use `FormProvider` and `useFormContext` to make the input field to work correctly without errors.

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm, FormProvider } from "react-hook-form";
import Input from "../../../components/atoms/form/Input";
[...]

const BasicInformation = () => {
  const methods = useForm();
  const onSubmit = (data: any) => console.log(data);

  return (
    <FormProvider {...methods}>
      <form onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        [...]
        <Input
          name="username"
          placeholder="Title"
          rules={{ required: "You must enter your first name." }}
        />
        [...]
      </form>
    </FormProvider>
  );
};
```

`input.tsx`

```
import React from "react";
import { useFormContext } from "react-hook-form";

const Input = ({
  name,
  rules,
  customStyle,
  ...rest
}: {
  name: string;
  rules: any;
  customStyle?: string;
  [x: string]: any;
}) => {
  const { register, formState } = useFormContext();

  const hasError = formState?.errors?.[name];
  const addedStyle = hasError ? "border-error-500" : "border-grey-200";

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        {...register(name, rules)}
        className={`text2 border rounded py-2 px-4 focus:outline-none ${addedStyle} ${
          customStyle && ` ${customStyle}`
        }`}
        {...rest}
      />
      <p className="text-error-500 text-xs">
        {formState?.errors?.[name]?.message?.toString()}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Input;
```